# Updating isLoading field on a redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have spinner that indicates my app is loading. Many reducers in my app need to be able to set this loader to either true or false.

**My Assumption:**
This field needs to live on the top most level of the state tree. Let's call it `isLoading`.

**The Problem:**
Redux reducers update their own portion of the state tree. What are some ways I can structure my reducers to update the `isLoading` field on the top most level?

I am familiar with `redux-thunk` but it seems like a bit of an overkill to dispatch an event on every action. But maybe I'm wrong and that is the correct approach. Also, it is certainly possible I am designing my state tree incorrectly.

For reference, I am currently using redux thunk as such:

```
export const fetchAssets = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    request
      .get('http://myapi.com/assets')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) {
          return dispatch(fetchAssetsFailure(err));
        }
        dispatch(fetchAssetsSuccess(res.body.data));
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducers receive all dispatched actions, so you want your `isLoading` reducer to react to every relevant action, instead of other reducers setting this value. Obviously, you can't use the `action.type` since you can't predict all relevant actions, and it will create a very cumbersome reducer. What you can do is add another field to the action, and this reducer will react to that field.

**Sample action creator:**

```
const createSampleAction = (payload, isLoading) => ({
    type: 'SAMPLE_ACTION',
    payload,
    meta: {
        isLoading
    }
});
```

**And the reducer:**

```
const isLoadingReducer = (state = false, { meta }) => {
  const isLoading = meta && meta.isLoading;

  if (isLoading !== undefined) {
      return isLoading;
  }

  return state;
}
```

If you're not comfortable with reducers that use the meta instead of the action type, you can create a middleware that will do the same property to dispatch showLoading / hideLoading actions, and the reducer will react to those actions:

```
const isLoadingMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => {
  next(action);
  const isLoading = action.meta && action.meta.isLoading;

  if (isLoading !== undefined) {
      dispatch(isLoading ? showLoading () : hideLoading());
  }
}
```